# Getting block characters ▒ scraping HTML

Tags: bash

html source code appears with blocks ▒ on a raspberry pi, but same command gives correct html source code on linux desktop.

Tried updating raspberry pi, running same command on different machines.

```
wget -q -O clair "https://www.amazon.com/Feline-Astrology-Horoscope-Never-Needed/dp/1733955402/ref=sr_1_1?crid=26EH0L6KDEVP9&keywords=feline+astrology&qid=1561512078&s=gateway&sprefix=feline+astr%2Caps%2C203&sr=8-1"
```

```
l4▒R▒\KR545▒▒SKB2s▒Lk▒▒▒ԒD▒▒Ģ▒▒[▒Ғ4]
.O`Y▒▒▒5▒.J▒▒d▒G▒x▒▒▒s▒LU▒▒?r_▒▒B▒▒▒L]`▒▒▒▒▒▒▒[{s▒Ȳ▒ߟsni▒h▒%▒▒▒▒J~;▒▒▒u▒▒k▒▒B@Y▒-}▒▒=▒▒S▒▒ ▒▒3▒ӏ_▒Y9I▒>K▒▒▒ *#o▒ow▒▒▒\▒▒7▒c▒▒▒9▒▒=u▒g}▒▒▒▒v▒▒▒$!▒{qB▒▒▒y▒K▒6i▒▒SQ▒kD▒▒C▒▒?:▒F▒▒▒z▒▒▒V▒w>SϾ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒>▒▒▒▒>▒ٺ▒<▒=▒▒d▒▒▒▒▒▒_▒D;▒i▒~ؽ▒▒;yy▒z▒▒q▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒e>▒▒▒y▒w>▒▒▒▒▒▒v▒~     Oky{▒▒▒▒}▒▒▒▒▒▒▒γ▒▒Ɲ▒G-▒O▒rd▒~4h▒
```

vs

normal HTML source code

Comment: That URL has a lot of junk in it. What if you try a simplified version, `https://www.amazon.com/dp/1733955402`?

Comment: Try adding the `-d` option (debug output), and see if that indicates anything useful. Especially look for content type and encoding.

Comment: Just tried the shortened link, and the -d option.  No luck.  BUT I did discover that this only occurs with amazon.com links.  even doing something as simple as "curl https://google.com" works fine, but the moment it's amazon is when it goes crazy